# node express fails intermittently when large request

Tags: node.js, express

I have an node express service working fine if request size is small.

However, when the request is large, it will fail intermittently, like success -> fail -> success -> fail...

Does anyone have same experience and give me some advice? Thanks.

FYI, I have included acceptance size limit in my code:

```
app.use(express.json({ limit: '100mb' }));
```

Comment: How can we reproduce your issue?

Comment: What kind of error do you see?